# Why removing powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted suddenly working but wasn't before

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ps, executionpolicy

I've a batch file run.bat which calls a python script (same issue if it's a ps1 instead of py script)

Contents of run.bat

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted
powershell python .\aTest.py
```

This was working fine until today where batch file is not invoking the python script.
The command window shows the following message:
"Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka/ms/pscore6"

I found from online that I can suppress this message with -nologon but that did not help other than removing the message.
I removed the following line powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted and script worked.
There was no user permissions change or anything made to the system between the last time it was successful and today.

Why this is happening is puzzling me and initially the -executionPolicy was added because without it, the script wasn't running.
Now it's the opposite, how can I figure out why this happened? What caused it?
Are there any difference having the extra PS flags and not if the user is a local admin group?

System is a Windows 10 and has one local admin user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted`

- This enters an *interactive* PowerShell session that requires a user to interactively submit `exit` in order to exit the session, and it is only *then* that the batch file continues executing.
- `-executionpolicy unrestricted` applies *only* to *that session* (process).
- Since neither the `-File` nor the `-Command` parameter are being used (the latter possibly *implicitly*, by passing command(s) only), PowerShell emits a "logo", i.e. a *copyright message*:

  ```bash
  Windows PowerShell
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  ```

  - Recent versions of Windows PowerShell *append* a message promoting the cross-platform, install-on-demand successor edition, [PowerShell (Core) v6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), to this message, so that you'll see the following:

    ```bash
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
    ```
  - Use `-NoLogo` to suppress this output; however, as implied above, this is *not* necessary if you pass *code to execute* as part of the call, either by passing a script file path (`.ps1`) to `-File` (`-f`), or by (possibly positionally) passing command(s) to `-Command` (`-c`). However, you *do* need `-NoLogo` with `-File` *if you combine it with `-NoExit`*.

> `powershell python .\aTest.py`

Generally speaking, there is *no* need to involve PowerShell in order to execute a Python script - directly invoking `python .\aTest.py` from a batch file should do.

Only if the call to the Python script relies on *initializations performed via PowerShell's [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)* (notably via the current user's `$PROFILE` file) would invocation via PowerShell be required.

- As an aside: use the `-NoProfile` [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) option in case you want to *suppress* loading of any profile files, which is *usually* the right thing to do, so as to ensure a predictable execution environment and avoid unnecessary processing.

If you do need to call via PowerShell, the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) does *not* apply to calling a *Python* script - it only applies to *PowerShell* scripts (`*.ps1`); if the *profile files* happen to call PowerShell scripts, use the following:

```bash
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command python .\aTest.py
```

<sup>Note: `Bypass` bypasses *all* checks regarding execution of `.ps1` scripts, whereas `Restricted` would still *prompt* before executing scripts downloaded *from the web*.</sup>

Note: Using the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter name explicitly isn't strictly necessary with `powershell.exe`, the *Windows PowerShell* CLI; however, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the [PowerShell (Core) 6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, now does require it.